# My macbook pro hard drive seems to be corrupted, should I replace it?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, hardware, performance

I have a 2,26GHz  mid-2009 macbook  pro  with 8Gb Ram and mountain  lion (mac os x 10.8.2).  Recently  my  computer doesn' t  stop freezing  and  I have to force the computer to shut down. Then  I cannot boot  at all the computer shows a flashing folder with a question mark. When I run disk utility from the installation cd then I am able to boot from the drive again but it will eventually starts lagging  after a few minutes of utilization with software's such as safari, skype or even the finder. I wanted to get a ssd recently. Will it fix this issue or the problem might lie elsewhere? I tried to boot from different sessions it always freezes at a moment, I have been able to run a virus scan disk and I didn't  find any virus nor trojans .

Comment: What does this sentence mean? "I wanted to get a sad recently"

Comment: Take your MBP to a dealer to have it checked for HW issues (especially HD and RAM).

Comment: AllInOne, I think he means he wanted to get an SSD recently.

Comment: If the problem is due to HDD failure, replacing it with an SSD will probably fix the problem. If the problem is on your logic board, replacing the HDD will do nothing. Follow Patrix suggestion.

Comment: By the way if the logic board is messed up... I will be messed up I can't afford a new laptop now and the apple care warranty has expired years ago.

Comment: I just downgraded the ram and put back 2gb of ram. It is slow but it seems to be working. I guess it's just a matter of time before it freezes.

Comment: I have a feeling that downgrading the ram might have solved the problem. Could it be due to faulty ram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the sata cable of the drive and it is working fine now.

Comment: Yay!
Since it's a pretty old Mac, I'll recommend that you do upgrade to an SSD. The performance boost is amazing in my experience.